# GSON not sending in UTF-8

Tags: java, gson

The following method sends a JSON reply. However on the receiving end I keep getting invalid characters, and UTF-8 isn't decoding the data. What am I doing wrong?

**Response to client = data output stream**

```
//Get the client request
            clientRequest = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectedClient.getInputStream())); //connectedclient = socket

            //Start response object
            responseToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectedClient.getOutputStream());


/**
     * Sends a JSON response for an object
     * @param objectToEncode
     * @throws Exception
     */
    private void sendJSONResponse(Object objectToEncode) throws Exception{

        //Encode object into JSON
        String jsonString = new Gson().toJson(objectToEncode);

        // HTTP Header... Status code, last modified
        responseToClient.writeBytes(HTTP_OK_STATUS_CODE);
        responseToClient.writeBytes(CONTENT_TYPE_JSON);
        responseToClient.writeBytes("Last-modified: "+ HelperMethods.now() +" \r\n");
        responseToClient.writeBytes("\r\n"); 

        // The HTTP content starts here
        responseToClient.writeBytes(jsonString);

    }
```

Comment: What is `responseToClient`? Are you writing your HTTP code yourself?

Comment: YES. THE HTTP code is listed (also responseToClient is a DataOutputStream

Comment: @WilliamFalcon, I have ArrayList object which contains many Chinese and Japanese Characters, How can I serialize them using GSON library, by usual mean I loose these characters and get **?** instead of them.

Comment: The problem is not in `GSON`. The problem is the byte encoding of your string. You need to mention the `utf-8` encoding when converting your string into the byte array that you are finally sending as a response

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I have no idea why you would write your own HTTP protocol code. It's a lot like writing your own XML parser: No matter how good a programmer you are, you are bound to get it wrong.

Anyway, as the [DataOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html) documentation states, doing `writeBytes` on a String will just discard its high eight bits. So what you get is... something, but not UTF8. What you should do is:

```
String jsonString = new Gson().toJson(objectToEncode);
byte[] utf8JsonString = jsonString.getBytes("UTF8");
responseToClient.write(utf8JsonString, 0, utf8JsonString.Length);
```

Comment: I agree, what would I use to do it for me then? and do you have a good tutorial?

Comment: The most lightweight embeddable HTTP java solution would be Jetty, I think. http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/ You can find lots of good tutorials here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial

Comment: Thanks. That fixed the issue (the byte array)

Comment: @JanDoerrenhaus, I have ArrayList object which contains many Chinese and Japanese Characters, How can I serialize them using GSON library, by usual mean I loose these characters and get **?** instead of them.

Comment: @PankajNimgade The JSON standard specifies UTF-8 as the only valid encoding. So when you get `?`-characters, it is not (or *should not* be) GSONs fault. Go ahead and ask your question (with example code, please) here on Stack Overflow as a new question. Ping me in a comment. I will be glad to help you.

Comment: @JanDoerrenhaus, you are right it wasn't Gson's fault, What i did was read the excel sheet and wrote Japanese characters from it to a text file then realized text file does not support UTF-8 by default so I wrote a .json file and i got the Japanese characters properly, sorry to bother you but got to learn something new :)

Comment: @PankajNimgade Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 14):

The first solution didn't work for me, I did this:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create();
String json = gson.toJson(objectToEncode);
```

Comment: GsonBuilder can be imported from `com.google.gson.GsonBuilder`: https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html

Answer (score 3):

Use the following code to encode

```
 response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF8"); // this line solves the problem
 response.setContentType("application/json");
```